# «Нищее, голое, развильчатое существо»

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, литература, переводы

> Нас трое здесь разбавленных, подфальшивленных. В тебе же — ничего заемного.
> Вот он, человек беспримесный, — вот это *нищее, голое, **развильчатое**
> существо*, и ничего сверх. Прочь, прочь все подмеси!
> [В. Шекспир. Король Лир](http://lib.ru/SHAKESPEARE/shks_lear2.txt) (акт III, сцена IV; перевод **О. Сороки**)

Из толкового словаря Ефремовой:
[развильчатый](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/233848/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9) — *прил.*, имеющий развилины; разветвлённый, развилистый.

Почему, с какой целью переводчик употребил такое редкое слово, да ещё и по отношению к человеку — **живому** существу? Какое значение вложено в это слово?
В литературе и в жизни мне оно не попадалось. А вам?
Хотелось бы знать ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

> Какое значение вложено в это слово?

В оригинале **forked**, которое образовано от **fork** — вилы, вилка и т.п. И я бы не подумал, что это слово там выглядит вполне естественно (но я не носитель того языка). В других переводах (во всех?) используется "приземлённый" вариант — **двуногое**. Если **forked** в оригинале звучит необычно для англичан и вызывает какие-то аллюзии, то **развильчатый** в переводе выглядит вполне уместно. В особенности, если знать оригинал и другие переводы. Но при первом прочтении я был в растерянности.

Comment: Может, Шекспир сравнивал человека с вилкой (вилкообразный)?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, правильный перевод — это ***двуногий***. Именное это значение обычно используется при анализе пьесы, например: http://allrefs.net/c16/175gz/p3/

Ценой пережитых им страданий Лир из **бедного, голого, двуногого** животного превращается в Человека, в своей простой человечности более великого, чем прежний Лир, облеченный королевским саном.

А слова ***развильчатый, развиловатый***  описаны у Даля, причем с негативным оттенком: https://slovar.cc/rus/dal/572853.html

Человек развиловат: сердце с думкой не в ладу. Двуличить, угождать и той и другой стороне. Он развиливает и дружит надвое. Развилье, тул. плохой, вялый либо хилый работник.